# Downloaded xls from python resulting in broken formatting vs manual download

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download the excel from this page: https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/index.cfm?event=notificationsList# and then extract data from the applicable cells.

Here is the code that I am using

```
import requests, os

os.chdir('Path')

dls = 'https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/index.cfm?event=ExportToExcel&StartRow=0'

resp = requests.get(dls)

with open('tester.xls', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(resp.content)
```

The download is successful, but the formatting is completely messed up (due to the XML?)

I tried changing the file type but it did not help.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: _The download is successful, but the formatting is completely messed up (due to the XML?)_ Are you certain that the file itself isn't already broken?

Comment: I tried it manually and it was working so assumed not. There is a working solution below that I will now use.

Comment: @blahblahvvvvv actually you were calling the `HTML` directly. not just the `XLS` content, So i've used `pandas.read_html()` where it's extract the table directly and then convert it to `dataframe`

Comment: I'm confused, that URL doesn't appear to lead to an XLS file.

Comment: Yeah, he downloaded the HTML from the main page and then saved it as a data frame using pandas. It was more so an easy workaround than a solution to my specific question.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη I read your comment after posting mine, thanks though

Comment: @blahblahvvvvv Would getting the data in XML also work for you?

Comment: Yeah it's fine, the end result is to add the urls and dates from many sites to one csv to I was able to work with your code. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "https://webgate.ec.europa.eu/rasff-window/portal/index.cfm?event=notificationsList")[0]
df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)

df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/9ca7193e6e83ae8b1478527ab8cab450/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: Perfecto! (also had to run pip3 install lxml)